# RabbitMQ : Sending Messages to another Queue if there's no consumers

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

Is there's a way in RabbitMQ to route messages in the queue when it has no consumer to another queue.
I'm thinking about using mixture of ***ttl*** and ***deadletter exchange*** so if messages exceeds some period of time the message will be expired and routed to deadletter exchange.
Although that solution will work but it has a risk that even the queue has consumers, messages can be expired if they exceed that expiry time because of high load.

so is there a better way to achieve that?

or a way to ensure the queue has consumers before publishing to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that we can check the number of consumer on that queue using `IModel.QueueDeclarePassive(string queue)` method which return `QueueDeclareOk`  as following

```
QueueDeclareOk result = _channel.QueueDeclarePassive(queueName);
if (result.ConsumerCount == 0)
{
    // publish to another queue or whatever you want
}
```